# Php check on external process

Tags: php, exe, external

I'm trying to add some php to my website to accomplish a task that would be outlined as:

```
check if foo.exe is running
if foo.exe is running display run.png
else display not.png

check if bar.exe is running
if foo.exe is running display run.png
else display not.png
```

The problem I'm having is that nothing I find online can even begin to tell me what methods I should be looking into. I've spent weeks learning PHP from sites like Codecademy, w3schools, etc. and none of them will give me the slightest clue on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `exec` and system on-board tools. http://php.net/exec

Comment: ^yup os tools, depending on the OS of course

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I did (thanks to suggestions) was this:

```
<?php
                $output = shell_exec('wmic process list brief | find /i "ventrilo_srv.exe"');
                echo $output;
            ?>
```